# How do I set ANT_OPTS under eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ant

When I build an application with ant in eclipse . I met java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.
How do I set ANT_OPTS under eclipse?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you right-click `build.xml`, select "Ant Build..." (with the ellipsis). This will bring up the run configuration dialog, and you'll be able to specify the memory arguments in the "JRE" tab.