# EMMA [MAIN_METHOD_NOT_FOUND] in Java 7

Tags: eclipse, code-coverage, java-7, emma

I have switched to the newest JDK 7 and I having a problem of running of emma code coverage using ant. It throws the following error:

```
emma:
 [emmajava] EMMA: no coverage data collected at runtime [all reports will be empty]
 [emmajava] [EMMA v2.0, build 5312]
 [emmajava] emmarun: [MAIN_METHOD_NOT_FOUND] application class does not have a runnable public main() method
 [emmajava] Exception in thread "main" com.vladium.emma.EMMARuntimeException: [MAIN_METHOD_NOT_FOUND] application class does not have a runnable public main() method
 [emmajava]     at com.vladium.emma.rt.AppRunner._run(AppRunner.java:497)
 [emmajava]     at com.vladium.emma.rt.AppRunner.run(AppRunner.java:97)
 [emmajava]     at com.vladium.emma.runCommand.run(runCommand.java:247)
 [emmajava]     at emmarun.main(emmarun.java:27)
 [emmajava] Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal local variable table length 5 in method <init>()V
 [emmajava]     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
 [emmajava]     at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
 [emmajava]     at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
 [emmajava]     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
 [emmajava]     at com.vladium.emma.rt.AppRunner._run(AppRunner.java:493)
 [emmajava]     ... 3 more
```

I have read [this question about the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010665/testng-emma-cobertura-coverage-and-jdk-7-result-in-classformaterror-and-verif) for resolving this error. But I cant update emma plugin due to following error.

```
No repository found at http://download.eclipselab.org/eclemma/beta/2.0.0/update/.
No repository found at http://download.eclipselab.org/eclemma/beta/2.0.0/update/.
```

How can I resolve this error?

How can I run emma code coverage in JDK 1.7?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Which EclEmma version are you using?

Comment: @assylias..no..I have ant script tool.I do not have idea about maven.Is there need to maven for code coverage?

Comment: @JoachimSauer I have used this EclEmma version 2.2.0.201210261515.

Comment: Did you try [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9583305/390513) has most votes?

Comment: @Kane thanks.That answer related to maven+cobertura plugin.I have used emma plugin.

Comment: I think it's same. You can specify the vm argument mentioned in that answer in your ant script when calling emma.

Comment: No @Kane.I have vm arguments for -XX:-UseSplitVerifier.but again same error(above).http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156147/how-do-i-set-ant-opts-under-eclipse. I have referred this link for adding jvm arguments into eclipse.

Comment: I think it's different. The run configuration is specifying a vm argument to run ANT. I think you ant script might forks another vm to run emma, make sure add that argument when running emma.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following inside `<emmajava>` solves the problem:

```
<jvmarg value="-XX:-UseSplitVerifier"/>
```

Comment: No.its not working.i have added this line junit target in ant script.still it shows same error.[or] if i did wrong plz correct me.where am i put this code?